# adding click event dynamically created highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

how we can add click event to highchart from chart object that we get after the creation.

Why i need this is, need to a create re-usable function to create a chart. after creation of chart I need to trigger click event to show some data in lightbox.

is there anything like addSeries eg:

```
chart.addSeries({
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]        
    });
```

for click?

```
chart.click(function(){})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchy

```
#chart
    -events
        -click
```

Check out the Highcharts [ref](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events)

Here is the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-click/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

Check [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
chart.on('click','serie selector',function(){code});
```